# brew install fails with 'The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified'

Tags: homebrew, github-packages

I'm trying to install `curl` via Homebrew using `brew install curl`.

However, the installation fails with:

> The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified (it is not valid JSON

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/brotli/manifests/1.0.9
Already downloaded: /Users/currentuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/922ce7b351cec833f9bd2641f27d8ac011005f8b1f7e1119b8271cfb4c0d3cd7--brotli-1.0.9.bottle_manifest.json
Error: curl: Failed to download resource "brotli_bottle_manifest"
The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified (it is not valid JSON):
/Users/currentuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/922ce7b351cec833f9bd2641f27d8ac011005f8b1f7e1119b8271cfb4c0d3cd7--brotli-1.0.9.bottle_manifest.json
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What does `brew doctor` output?

Comment: almost empty. but most errors I met is `Error: openssl@3: Failed to download resource "ca-certificates_bottle_manifest"
The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified (it is not valid JSON): `

Comment: `Error: curl: Failed to download resource "ca-certificates_bottle_manifest"
The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified (it is not valid JSON): 
/Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c95acf8107b31ec83053f411f74e85b2626e1a0c051467aff6b98acf996883d7--ca-certificates-2022-07-19_1.bottle_manifest.json
Error: 'curl' must be installed and in your PATH!
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet` any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Try [uninstalling homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) and then reinstalling it.

Comment: `~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: none`

Comment: This just happened to me as well--it was solved by removing all the faulty manifest.json files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was resolved after delete `/Users/currentuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/922ce7b351cec833f9bd2641f27d8ac011005f8b1f7e1119b8271cfb4c0d3cd7--brotli-1.0.9.bottle_manifest.json`
and run `brew install curl` again

Comment: Had a similar problem with a different package on my system (open-mpi), and deleting these cached downloads fixed it for me too.

Comment: Had the same problem with kbr5 & postgresql. You saved my day!

Comment: For me the only thing that worked was to delete _all_ files in the .../Homebrew/downloads/ directory, then run brew install curl. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This command fixed the issue for me:

```
brew cleanup
```

Comment: `brew cleanup --prune=all` to fix issues with corporate vpn replacing files with warnings

Answer (score 2):

It might be using the installed curl instead of system curl.
From [man brew](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)

set HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL

Comment: tried `HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1 brew install openssl` does not work

Answer (score 2):

I have also this problem with brew install php
the problem persists even after deleting all the files from

`/Users/currentuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/`

and

`brew install php again`

i have also tried

`HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1 brew install openssl`

Comment: my prevoius download issue caused by my company vpn/proxy. After turn off company proxy, delete cached download, re-install again, the issue is resloved. Please pay attention whether you have some vpn/proxy is on.

Comment: @new2cpp he was right for my issue. 
For me company vpn needed to be enabled since I am using company brew.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: ensure you can access https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core

---

In my case, GitHub Packages ([ghcr.io](https://ghcr.io)) was being blocked by our corporate firewall. By default, Homebrew uses https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core as the download source for bottles. This source URL is set by the [`HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#environment) environment variable.

The corporate firewall was intercepting the request for the GitHub Package manifest & responding with an HTML block page. Then, Homebrew stored and tried to parse the block page as a package manifest, which of course won't work. This results in the above 'corrupted' error.

To verify if this is the cause, try either of the below:

- Open https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core in a web browser to see if it's accessible or blocked
- Change the manifest file extension e.g. `xxx.bottle_manifest.json` to `.html` and try opening it to see if it displays a block page

```bash
mv /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/xxx.bottle_manifest.json page.html
open page.html
```

You need to request for `https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core` to be unblocked.