# Brew install package fails with corrupted json with mac m1 ventura Version 13.4.1

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I have installed brew as suggested through official documentation.
Haven't had any issues with installation and also verified brew doctor, update etc but when I try to install a package it always fails with following error

`Error: mongosh: Failed to download resource "brotli_bottle_manifest" The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified (it is not valid JSON):  /Users/XXXXXXXXXXXX/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/922ce7b351cec833f9bd2641f27d8ac011005f8b1f7e1119b8271cfb4c0d3cd7--brotli-1.0.9.bottle_manifest.json`

Irrespective of the package I always receive this error.

I checked brew version
`~ % brew --version Homebrew 4.1.2`

`~ % brew doctor Your system is ready to brew.`

~ % brew update => `Already up-to-date.`

~ % echo $PATH =>  `/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin`

brew install mongosh --verbose -d. =>  `/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading mongosh from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading node@16 from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading brotli from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading cmake from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading c-ares from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading icu4c from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading libnghttp2 from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading pkg-config from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading libuv from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading autoconf from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading m4 from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading automake from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading libtool from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading sphinx-doc from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading docutils from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading python@3.11 from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading mpdecimal from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading openssl@3 from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading ca-certificates from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading sqlite from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading readline from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading xz from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading pygments from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading python@3.10 from API /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaAPILoader): loading gdbm from API ==> Fetching dependencies for mongosh: brotli, c-ares, icu4c, libnghttp2, libuv, ca-certificates, openssl@3 and node@16 ==> Fetching brotli ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/brotli/manifests/1.0.9 Already downloaded: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/922ce7b351cec833f9bd2641f27d8ac011005f8b1f7e1119b8271cfb4c0d3cd7--brotli-1.0.9.bottle_manifest.json Error: mongosh: Failed to download resource "brotli_bottle_manifest" The downloaded GitHub Packages manifest was corrupted or modified (it is not valid JSON):  /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/922ce7b351cec833f9bd2641f27d8ac011005f8b1f7e1119b8271cfb4c0d3cd7--brotli-1.0.9.bottle_manifest.json`

~ % brew config =>  `HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.1.2 ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew HEAD: 3db1acf3e38e270af4e1c3f214622bbfb18f830e Last commit: 14 hours ago Core tap JSON: 27 Jul 17:50 UTC HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: [] HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8 Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm Clang: 14.0.3 build 1403 Git: 2.39.2 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git Curl: 7.88.1 => /usr/bin/curl macOS: 13.4.1-arm64 CLT: 14.3.1.0.1.1683849156 Xcode: N/A Rosetta 2: false`

brew reset and also making sure brew shell is in path and .zshrc file. Any suggestions or help on this..
Earlier before I upgraded to mac 13.X i never had this issue. I unchecked rosetta option on terminal info and still receive the same error. With rosetta checked in it is installing in usr/local folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homebrew broken and unable to install anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73300645/homebrew-broken-and-unable-to-install-anything)

Comment: Hi I have tried almost all the answers that I found including the suggestion provided and github suggestions but nothing helped me